# Filter validate, returning on first occurrence of an error

Tags: php, validation, filter-var

I currently using the basic PHP functions like isset & is_numeric to validate user input. I am looking to update my code to the new PHP filter functions introduced with PHP 5.2. I have forms with multiple inputs and I am looking for a way to use the filter_input_array function so that it if an error is found before going through all the validations false is returned. For example.

If I validate a number & a email. If the number is in-valid, false should be returned without validating the email. Is there a way to achieve this using filter_input_array.

Comment: `var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));` from http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: @Glavić, He says, if any one filter fails, do not perform the other filters which is available on the filter array.

Comment: If you use `filter_input_array`, it validates all of the inputs. If you want to check them one at a time, use `filter_input` instead.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thanks. Thats exactly what my question was about.